# Random Activity opens instead of Launcher Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

After exiting from my app if i open it again random activities open instead of Launcher Activity. The problem continues even after putting  in manifest. I have set the category as DEFAULT as shown in the code below. In the main activity i have put the code (given below) to exit the app on back press.

```
 //Android Manifest -- i have set all activities as DEFAULT except LAUNCHER activity.
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>



@Override// In Main Activity I have put this code to exit app when back is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
    }
```

Comment: Does it open a random activity after you close the app by pressing the back button or the home button?

Comment: @ParagKadam back button. home button will definitely open the previous activity

Comment: Any specific reason to get rid of the `super.onBackPressed();` in your `onBackPressed()` ?

Comment: @ParagKadam didn't get you. Sry

Comment: Don't override the `onBackPressed() ` if you do not have a reason to do so.

Comment: @ParagKadam I have to. Its a Must in my case

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the category to LAUNCHER like this

```
`<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

`